# Dual-tone background for text in CSS

Tags: css

I'm trying to get a background for some text that is dual-tone, or the top half is one color and the bottom half is another.  I have attached a link to a picture of what this should look like.  Any ideas on how I can achieve this?  Thanks, in advance, for the help!

Michael

http://michaelphillips.dropmark.com/12339/296433

Comment: Sorry, they wouldn't let me put it up because I'm a new user.  Let me figure out another way.

Comment: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/8993619/Screen%20shot%202012-03-07%20at%208.46.27%20PM.png

Comment: Have you seen this: http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/css-gradient-text-effect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Three ways come to mind:

**One**: Most Cross Browser (CSS1): Make a `1px` wide image of the two colors, probably about 30px tall for each color, then

```
<span class="duoTone">wrap your text in a span</span>
```

and set the

```
.duoTone {background-image: url(path/to/your/img.jpg) left center repeat-x;}
```

**Two**: Less friendly to older browsers (CSS2): Same `span` wrapper as above but with this css ([see fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HTDjS/3/)).

```
.duoTone {
   position: relative;
}

.duoTone:before,
.duoTone:after {
   content: '';
   position: absolute;
   top: 0;
   left: 0;
   width: 100%;
   height: 50%;
   z-index: -1;
   background-color: #bbbbbb;
}

.duoTone:after {
   top: auto;
   bottom: 0;
   background-color: #888888;
}
```

**Three**: Sleek, but only for newer browsers (CSS3): Same `span` code as #1 ([see fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HTDjS/15/)).

```
.duoTone {
   background-color: #888888 ;
   background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 100%, color-stop(.5, rgba(255, 255, 255, .4)), color-stop(.5, transparent), to(transparent));
   background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(rgba(255, 255, 255, .4) 50%, transparent 50%, transparent);
   background-image: -o-linear-gradient(rgba(255, 255, 255, .4) 50%, transparent 50%, transparent);
   background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(255, 255, 255, .4) 50%, transparent 50%, transparent);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, ScottS!  I ended up finding this resource: http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/ and was able to create a two-tone gradient with a small sliver of transparency inbetween.  See fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Buaen/1/